# C# Query Language for building LDAP queries

Tags: c#, ldap, linq-to-ldap

does anyone know of any strongly typed language for building LDAP queries in C#? I'd like to move away from

```
(&(|(objectClass=user)(objectClass=group)(objectClass=computer)(objectClass=contact))((objectGUID={0})))
```

and preferably have a fluid api for building logical queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can try Linq to LDAP

here you have a [tutorial](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2007/04/05/the-iqueryable-tales-linq-to-ldap-part-0.aspx)

Comment: That looks awesome, why didn't I find this earlier!?

Comment: After a quick glance it has one limitation, though: You can only build queries for ONE object type i.e. user. Searching over Users OR groups OR computers seems impossible, let's see if we can hack this in...

Answer (score 0):

http://linqtoad.codeplex.com/ is a good one

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @DesertIvy, Normally I would agree with you, but this is not some random link to some article - it is the home page of a project on codeplex.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you can also check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace.

Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

if(user != null)
{
   // do something here....     
}

// find the group in question
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere");

// if found....
if (group != null)
{
   // iterate over members
   foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers())
   {
      Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.StructuralObjectClass, p.DisplayName);
      // do whatever you need to do to those members
   }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD! Much easier than the earlier `DirectoryEntry` approach...